# Wait until some async code will be executed , then proceed to next step in webpack 5 hooks

Tags: webpack, hook

```
 plugins: [
  {
    apply(compiler) {
      compiler.hooks.beforeCompile.tapAsync(
        'GetLanguagesPlugin',
        async (_, callback) => {
          const res = await loginUser({ core, email, password })
          callback()
        }
      )
    }
  }
]
```

Above you can see example of plugin I want to write , there is some async actions which I want to fait on , and then proceed after those actions will be done , but compiler doesn't wait on those async functions , and move forward , how can I wait on some async actions , and execute some code , before compilation will be started  ?

Answer (score 0):

[Search for hooks in documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/compiler-hooks/) that are marked as `AsyncSeriesHook`